# Angular2 ExceptionHandler not working

Tags: angular, exceptionhandler

I've searched around quite a bit and haven't found anything that is helping me get over the hump.  I think that I have implemented the Angular2 ExceptionHandler as required, but it is never getting called.

Main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ExceptionHandler, Injector , provide, Provider} from '@angular/core';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';    // <-- load in global routes and bootstrap them
import { ErrorHandler } from './errorhandler/error-handler.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent,[ 
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: ErrorHandler})
])
```

error-handler.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Injectable, ExceptionHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { APP_PROVIDERS } from '../app.providers';

@Component({ 
  moduleId: module.id,
  template: `Error happened here!!!!`,
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
  providers: [ APP_PROVIDERS ]
})

@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandler extends ExceptionHandler {

  call (exception: any, stackTrace?: any, reason?: string): void {


  }

}
```

I have an HTTP error that I'm forcing to occur in one of my services (to test the exception handling) and would expect my "global" handler to get called.  Am I missing something?  Unfortunately, not a whole lot of documentation out there right now...

TIA.

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea if that's the problem, but don't use a `Component` as an error handler. That's not the way to do it.

You just have to (not even necessary, but it looks cooler) implement the `ExceptionHandler` interface, not extend it. No need for `@Injectable()` (yet... maybe this handler will have dependencies in the future, and then it is necessary)

```
export class ErrorHandler implements ExceptionHandler {
  call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
    // do something with the exception
  }
}
```

You can keep your bootstrap the way it is